# how to check code coverage of specific controller in mvc?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, tfs, code-coverage

I want to know the steps for analyzing code coverage of any specific controller.

I am working on ASP.NET MVC4 with Visual Studio 2012 and TFS setup.

> > I know that with can analyze code coverage of all of the controllers from test explorer window "Analyze code coverage for all controller" option.

But i want to check the code coverage of any one controller.

Answer (score 1):

First you can group them by the Class Name in the Test Explorer window. Then find the specific Controller you need the Code Coverage. Then Right Click on the at Controller, and select "Analyze Code Coverage For Selected Tests". This would produce the Code Coverage for the specific Controller you selected. Note that you see all other Controllers/Types have been instrumented in the Code Coverage Result window, however they don't have any  coverage result. It would just say Covered (Blocks) = 0.